# Números pares numa array com for - PHP

Tags: php, array, if, for

Olá, gostaria de entender onde o meu código está errado. Preciso que seja filtrado somente os número pares da array usando o for. Porém retorna a seguinte resposta pra mim - "O filtro não está funcionando muito bem".

```
function filtraArray($umArray) {
    $resultado = [];

    for($i = 0; $i > count($umArray); $i++){
      if ($umArray[$i] % 2 == 0) {
        echo $resultado = $umArray[$i];
      }
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Obrigada :)

Comment: Na linha `echo $resultado = $umArray[$i];` você está substituindo o valor da variável `$resultado` toda vez que um valor é par. O correto seria `$resultado[] = $umArray[$i];`. Desta forma, toda vez que um número for par, será criado um índice na variável `$resultado`.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei duas falhas no seu código:

1) Você escreveu que `for` deve se repetir enquanto `i` for **maior** do que o número de itens no array, enquanto na verdade ele deve se repetir enquanto  `i` for **menor** do que o número de itens no array.

2) A variável `$resultado` é um array, e já que quer os números pares dentro dela, deve incluir os novos valores e não substituir. Então a inclusão será feita da seguinte forma: `$resultado[] = $umArray[$i];`

Abaixo o código corrigido, espero ter ajudado!

```
function filtraArray($umArray) {  
    $resultado = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($umArray); $i++){
      if ($umArray[$i] % 2  == 0) {
        $resultado[] = $umArray[$i];
      }
    }

    return $resultado;
}

$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,15,654,565678,87978977];
$resultado = filtraArray($array);
print_r($resultado);
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou, nem me atentei a isso!

Comment: Por nada, caso tenha ajudado, lembre de clicar em +1 e marcar a minha resposta como escolhida!